# Terminate the continuous execution of CMAKE target?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, cmake

I have added custom target to my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_custom_target (
        patch
        COMMAND echo "Creating build"
        COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} && sudo bash a.sh
        COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} && sudo bash b.sh  name
        COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} && sudo bash b.sh  address

        DEPENDS authorise
        DEPENDS copy
    )
```

What happen in above case is, I have terminated the execution of `a.sh` with `exit 0` on certain condition, but after terminating that script `cmake` is moving further to execute `b.sh`

What I want is, when I terminated from first script, the execution of `cmake target` also has to be terminate. I don't want to go for `b.sh` to execute it.

Is there any way that we can stop or terminate the execution of `CMAKE target`

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series of `COMMAND`s in `add_custom_target` is translated to `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`.

So, instead of exiting with code 0, you have to return something else. [Catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal](https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash) in your shell scripts and return non-zero code:

```
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
        exit 1
}
```

Comment: can you able to elaborate more will understand more neatly , as I am newbie in `cmake` @arrowd

Comment: add answer by taking reference of code mention in question

Comment: You don't need to change CMake code. Change scripts by adding Ctrl+C handler.